# Accessing data from Restful web service asynchronously

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am writing an android application where all my data is expose using web service. I am writing a wrapper class to fetch  data from the services called DataManager.

```
public class DataManager{

public DataManager (){}


public String getValue ()
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet ("some url");

    try 
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        if (response.getStatusLine ().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity ();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            return result;
        }
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

When I call this method a RuntimeException is generated on the UI thread. How can I refactor this
code and fetch the values from the webservice and return these values asynchronously. [NOTE] I am writing this for some team members so they can use it to get data from the service so I want it to be has easy has possible for them to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`. Doing networking (and in general lengthy operations) on UI thread is no-no on Android.

Here you got with [AsyncTask fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and some [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)
And here you got with [IntentService fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

I'd use AsyncTask myself (IntentService's jobs are queued), but be [aware about change in the way it is handled in newer APIs](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html). Not a big deal (just a few more code lines), though

Comment: AsyncTask jobs are also queued in newer versions, which is a feature rather than a bug. Multiple simultaneous threads are difficult to manage correctly. For downloading data from a RESTful web service, there's probably not much demand for simultaneous processing anyway; it's hard to think of real-life scenarios in which you have to run multiple downloads from the *same* IntentService.

Comment: The link in last paragraph of my answer deals with regression concerning queuing async task. The trick is you can get rid of it, whiche IntentService jobs are queued by design. I wrote couple of mobile clients and there's lot of scenarios when simultaneous access is required. Therefore I use AsyncTask (via `executeOnExecutor()` of course) for networking, instead of IntentService.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend giving David Chandler's [basic HTTP client](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/a-basic-http-client-for-android-and-more/) library for Android a try.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to use an IntentService. That gives you a background thread and a way to pass it a URL. Depending on how much data you have, you can either dump it into a local file or store it in a database.

If you do the database route, you can load the data asynchronously in an Activity using AsyncTaskLoader, or do full access using AsyncTask. And, with some extra overhead but much more simple coding, you can stick the data in a ContentProvider and then use a CursorLoader in your Activity.

**Above all, never do network operations or database operations on the UI thread.** Use your Activity as a "presenter" (an intelligent "view") and put all the controller and model stuff in the background.

Comment: How can I get this with a IntentService and have the same effect has what was implemented above. For example I want someone to call the datamanager class to get data from the webservice. The DataManager would hand over this to the intentService and returns the result to the user once the service fetchs the data and hands it back to the dataManager. So a call would look like this DataManager data = new DataManager (); data.getValue. The problem is how to make the dataManager get back data from the intentservice?(I am kinda lost so please bare with me)